# How to solve mixed differential equations? Or how to assign the dPsdt = o in first iteration and it will get value after iterations

Tags: differential-equations

Error generates like this: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dPsdt' referenced before assignment

```
dL1dt = (m_si*(h1-hf) + pi*di*alphai_1*L1*(Tm1-Ts1) - d13*dPsdt)/d11
dL2dt = (m_si*hf-m_so*hg + pi*di*alphai_2*L2*(Tm2-Ts2)- d21 * dL1dt -d23*dPsdt- 
          d24*dhodt)/d22
dPsdt = (m_so*(hg-ho) + pi*di*alphai_3*L3*(Tm3-Ts3)-d31*dL1dt-d32*dL2dt - 
        d34*dhodt)/d33
dhodt = (m_si - m_so -(d41*dL1dt) - (d42*dL2dt) - (d43*dPsdt))/d44 

dzdt = [dL1dt, dL2dt, dPsdt, dhodt, dTm1dt, dTm2dt, dTm3dt, dTp1dt, dTp2dt, dTp3dt]

return dzdt
```

Comment: please make sure to share a minimal, reproducible code snippet of the problem so that others can understand and help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your derivatives are implicitly defined by some linear system

```
A*dxdt = b
```

which you try to solve via Gauss-Seidel iteration. This you have to actually implement as iteration, that is, several passes over the system of equations. Note that you need a convergence condition like diagonal dominance so that that works at all.

But for these small dimensions you can be faster and more exact by using

```
dxdt = nump.linalg.solve(A,b)
```